# Blank white screen appears after a while using windows on kiosk mode

Tags: windows, screen, chromium, touchscreen, kiosk

I am using Windows and Kioware to start my Intel Stick computer in kioks mode. The kiosk is showing a webpage and everything looks fine, until a white screen randomly appears and there is no change to interact with the webpage.

I use Kioware lite for Windows that runs the kiosk using Chromium.
I use a Samsung Touch Screen TV with HDMI connected to an Intel stick (Windows 10).

Can anyone tell me the possible causes for this to happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this is a programming question can you [edit] it to make that clear and add a [mcve]? If it is a question about using kioware perhaps it would get better answers at https://superuser.com/

Comment: This was likely a bug in KioWare's installer. An issue was discovered with the installer that did not correctly remove past installations, which resulted in a problem with the underlying Chromium browser. For most customers, this resulted in seeing a white screen at some point. The installer issue was resolved in version 8.19, so I'd recommend installing any version newer than that.